# Adjust vertical space of headings carried out by different line spacing

Tags: sectioning, koma-script, line-spacing, setspace

A question related to the koma script guide. As recommended on page 57, I set the table of contents, glossary, list of tables and list of figures with the standard line spacing. The text should have a line spacing of 1.5.

When I do this, the title of the chapter is under the caption of the bibliography. Is there an easy way to remove this problem?

```
\documentclass[
a4paper,                         
fontsize=11,                    
BCOR=10mm,
DIV=11
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}                    
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}                
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}                        
\usepackage{microtype}    
\usepackage[
    style=numeric, 
    maxnames=1,
    bibencoding=latin1,
    backend=bibtex8,
    defernumbers=true,
    hyperref=true,
    alldates=long
]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[hyphenbreaks]{breakurl}
\usepackage{setspace}

\begin{filecontents}{bachelorarbeit_lit.bib}
@ONLINE{java96,
    author = {{Sun Microsystems}},
    title = {JavaSoft ships Java 1.0},
    year = {1996},
    month = {1},
    url = {http://findarticles.com/p/articles/mi_m0EIN/is_1996_Jan_23/ai_17853565/?tag=content;col1},
    urldate = {2011-03-02},
    sortname = {Sun},
    keywords = {www}
}
\end{filecontents}

\bibliography{bachelorarbeit_lit}

\begin{document}
\onehalfspacing
\chapter{Test}
Test \cite{java96}

\singlespacing
\DIV=current
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx! It's not necessary to sign your questions (as there is already a box with your username below it) or to begin them with a greeting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it is working:

```
\AfterTOCHead{\singlespacing}

\renewcommand*{\glossarypreamble}{\singlespacing}

\makeatletter
\preto\blx@env@bibliography{\singlespacing}
\makeatother
```